# Domain size constraint on satisfiability

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I need to prove whether the following statement is true or false:

> let $L$ be a first order language with the following signature $\sigma = \{{p_1, p_2, p_3}\}$ which are all 1-ary predicates. Does there exist a formula $A$ in $L$ such that there exists a structre and a variable assginment that satisfies $A$ only if the size of the domain of the structure is at least 5

Now, it seems wrong to me, because we don't have any way to "compare" 2 items with this signature. What direction should I go in? thanks.

Comment: Apart from the "only if", this exercise is sloppily worded to the point of incomprehensibility. Since "the structure" is mentioned _after_ "only if", its existential quantifier must range over the entire "only if", so it seems you're being asked to decide
$$ \exists A : \exists \mathcal S,\sigma : \bigl( \mathcal S,\sigma \vDash A \implies |\mathcal S|\ge 5 \bigr) $$
This is trivially true; just take $A$ to be a contradiction and $\mathcal S$ to be something with at most $4$ elements. And it doesn't even help to write $\Leftrightarrow$ instead of $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The question meant $\ \forall S$, sorry for the bad wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem said if and only if, rather than only if. Otherwise the question is trivial (any self-contradictory formula would be fine).

Think about unary predicates as subsets. As a hint, I show you the solution of a simpler problem. You can modify the proof to get a solution for your problem.

Modified problem: same signature, and we are looking for a formula which is satisfyable in some structure $A$ if and only if $|A|\geq 8$.

The formula should say there exists an element in all $8$ possible Boolean combinations that you can express using $p_1, p_2, p_3$. 
So there is an $x$ with $p_1(x)\wedge p_2(x)\wedge p_3(x)$. 
Also there is a $y$ with $\neg p_1(x)\wedge p_2(x)\wedge p_3(x)$. 
Etc. with the remaining six combinations.

The conjuction of these 8 requirements is equivalent to the structure having at least $8$ elements. (Think about it).

Now modify the proof to get it with $5$ instead of $8$.

Comment: Ah, you can construct a $DNF$ formula using 5 of these clauses with a different variable in each clause, and that will work as if you assume 4 items then 2 clauses have the same variable assignment, and so you will have a predicate and its negation because at least one of them will appear flipped in the other clause. Thanks!

Comment: Correction, you need to join all of the clauses with $\wedge$s, in DNF it won't work.

Comment: The exercise seems to be trivial no matter whether it says "only if" or "if and only if". It looks like you're reinterpreting to mean: Does there exist an $A$ such that $$\{ n \mid A\text{ is satisfied by some structure of size }n\} = \{n\mid n\ge 5\} ?$$ Granted, this is definitely a more interesting question than what the exercise actually asked...

Comment: @Henning Makholm I did not understand this. Why is the problem trivial with iff?

Comment: @A.Pongrácz: See my comment on the question. It is trivial to choose $A$ and the structure such that both sides of the "(if and?) only if" are false.